# TI-Basic String to number

Tags: string, numbers, ti-basic

Essentially, my code returns a string which only contains a 1 or 2 digit integer, such as "8" or "10". Is there any way to convert this to an actual number, such as one that could be then stored in a list or matrix?

Comment: Did you try [this link](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/number-to-string)?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the string is in Str1, you can simply do this:

```
expr(Str1->X
```

This will evaluate whatever crazy math is inside of Str1 (in this case, it's just a straight up number) and store it into X.